# IS NULL check not working on list in JPA SQL Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have following JPA Query with a where clause:

```
@Query("SELECT P FROM ParentEntity P \n" +
"INNER JOIN P.childEntities C \n" +
"WHERE C.childId IN (:childIds)")
List<ParentEntity> findByChildIds(@Param("childIds") List<UUID> childIds);
```

*childId* column is *notnull* in table, all rows have value for this column.

Query works fine when the *childIds* param has values. But *childIds* is an optional parameter, it may be an empty list or null, in which case I would like to ignore the where clause and simply return

```
SELECT P FROM ParentEntity P \n" +
    "INNER JOIN P.childEntities C
```

So I modified the query to this:

```
@Query("SELECT P FROM ParentEntity P \n" +
"INNER JOIN P.childEntities C \n" +
"WHERE ((:childIds) IS NULL OR C.childId IN (:childIds))")
List<ParentEntity> findByChildIds(@Param("childIds") List<UUID> childIds);
```

Now, when *childIds* is empty (= []), this query returns 0 results as `(:childIds) IS NULL` is false and `C.childId IN (:childIds)` is always false as well. But I want all the rows in this case.

and when *childIds* is *null*, then it throws an exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $1
```

Instead of exception, I would like all the rows to return here as well.

Comment: Try adding `or :childIds = []`

Comment: gives QuerySyntaxException

Comment: Try to use `COALESCE(:childIds, null) is null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really have 2 separate queries, so rather than bury the logic in SQL, move it into a `default` method choses the appropriate straightforward JPA method:

```
default List<ParentEntity> findByChildIds(List<UUID> childIds) {
    if (childIds == null || childIds.isEmpty()) {
        return getAll();
    }
    return getByChildIds(childIds);
}

@Query("SELECT P FROM ParentEntity P \n" +
"INNER JOIN P.childEntities C \n" +
"WHERE C.childId IN (:childIds)")
List<ParentEntity> getByChildIds(@Param("childIds") List<UUID> childIds);

@Query("SELECT P FROM ParentEntity P \n" +
"INNER JOIN P.childEntities C")
List<ParentEntity> getAll();
```

This makes the SQL easier to read and the logic easier to follow, plus it gives the database a better chance to optimize well.

Name all the methods here as you like - they don't need to employ JPA method keywords.

I have used this approach to good effect in production.

Comment: Yes, in the end had to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can create 2 requests and choose which one you want to use depending on your parameter.